# getting runtime error in terminal whereas it's okay in xcode

Tags: c, clang

the below one is my code in a competition, i just started to do these things. so when i compiled this in xcode it is fine but when i compiled it in terminal it is giving as error. can some one spot the error please.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n, i,count=0,ans,prev=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==0)
            ans++;
        else if(a[i]==3)
        {
            if(i>=1)
            {if(a[i-1]==1||a[i-1]==2)
                prev=a[i-1];
            }
            count++;
        }
        else if(a[i]==2||a[i]==1)
        {if(i!=0){
            if(a[i]!=prev&&((count-1)%2)==0)
                ans++;
            if(a[i]==prev&&(count%2)==0)
                ans++;
            prev=a[i];
            count=0;}
        }
    }   
    printf("%d",ans);
}
```

Comment: Don't you think it would be a good idea to tell us exactly what the error is?

Comment: Step 1: compile with `-Wall` and fix all of the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code I can see some errors

1. Check the return values of your `scanf` calls as they should [return the number of values parsed](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)
2. `ans` is not guaranteed to be initialized to `0` it could be any value left there ( I would guess hat running it in Xcode or a debugger would have initialized it )
3. Put curly braces around your conditional statement, you are a beginner and putting curly braces would help you read your own code.

Comment: thank you so much it was the 2 one I missed. It worked now.